# Blender with Python - Freestyle Linesets

Tags: python

I have encountered a problem with Python scripting for Blender.

I have a script which recieves meshes via an external source, and adds them to the scene.
A specific type of mesh is added to the second layer. If such a mesh is created, a second RenderLayer is created and Freestyle-Rendering is activated.
So far, all of this works as I wish.
But I want to add specific Freestyle-Brush-Color to each of this meshes, and so I want to create a Lineset with a linked LineStyle for each one.

Problem now: How can I create and manage the LineSets. I can create a LineSet for the active RenderLayer but without name, and the creation method does not return a handle to that LineSet. How do I cleanly and efficiently retrive the newly created LineSet so that I can add a LineStyle and other settings to it?

My RenderLayer-related code so far:

```
LineRenderLayer = None
    if not "PolyLineLayer" in bpy.context.scene.render.layers:
        bpy.context.scene.render.use_freestyle = True
        bpy.context.scene.layers = [True] * 2 + [False] * 18
        bpy.context.scene.render.layers["RenderLayer"].layers = \
            [True] + [False]*19
        bpy.ops.scene.freestyle_lineset_remove()
        LineRenderLayer = bpy.context.scene.render.layers.new("PolyLineLayer")
        LineRenderLayer.use_freestyle = True
        LineRenderLayer.layers = [False] + [True] + [False] * 18
    else:
        LineRenderLayer = bpy.context.scene.render.layers["PolyLineLayer"]


    bpy.context.scene.render.layers.active = LineRenderLayer

    bpy.ops.scene.freestyle_lineset_add()
```

The last line is the main problem. It does not take a name as parameter and does not return anything. But I need that created Lineset for further configuration.

I use Blender in version 2.70

Thank you for your help!

Greetings,
Dragonseel

Comment: You can access the linesets data from `bpy.context.scene.render.layers['PolyLineLayer'].freestyle_settings.linesets[]` while I expected `....linesets.new()` to work, it doesn't, so I'm not certain of a better way to create new LineSets.

Comment: So I just assume the new lineset will be added as the last entry in the lineset collection? Because I do not know anything about it. It gets a name like "LineSet X" but I don't know the number. Searching for it would be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an API design bug that the collection of line sets does not have a .new() and .remove() method.
I will address this problem as soon as possible, preferably in the next Blender 2.71 release.

Comment: Fixes were made in the Blender code repository and will be part of Blender 2.71.